# How to execute gradle build command through Main Method of Java

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to execute the gradle build command (using cmd prompt) through the main method of the java class.

```
public class GradleScriptEditor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String command_to_be_executed = "gradle build";
        String directory_location = "C:\\mycode\\ws";

        String[] command = {command_to_be_executed};
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        builder = builder.directory(new File(directory_location));

        Process p = builder.start();
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(directory_location+ "/mylog.log"));
        outputStream.write(p.getInputStream().readAllBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "gradle build" (in directory "C:\\mycode\\ws"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at practice.GradleScriptEditor.main(GradleScriptEditor.java:16)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:158)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
    ... 2 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please note that when I am using ipconfig to test my code, it is working fine.

Please advise what I can do to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation `public ProcessBuilder(String... command)`

> Constructs a process builder with the specified operating system program and arguments. This is a convenience constructor that sets the process builder's command to a string list containing the same strings as the command array, in the same order

It means you need to pass command as

```
String[] command = {"gradle", "build"};
```

Comment: It didn't work still.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of launching a process, use the [Gradle Tooling API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/third_party_integration.html#sec:embedding_quickstart). It's not possible to teach you how to use the Tooling API here, but I'm leaving couple of links for you to explore.

https://www.sobyte.net/post/2022-02/gradle-tooling-api/

https://gist.github.com/buzztaiki/2046728